# how to route 53 to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Currently I already created elasticbeanstalk with docker platform and running well.

My problem here :
I want to route my subdomain via route 53 redirect to my elastic beanstalk.
I already go to route 53 and change my subdomain CNAME pointing to my elastic beanstalk.
I check with dig command :

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8115
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;staging.mydomain.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
staging.mydomain.com    145 IN  CNAME   myelasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.
myelasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. 36 IN A 175.xx.xx.xx
myelasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. 36 IN A 52.xx.xx.xx

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: xx.xx.xx.xx
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 19 10:36:34 
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 140
```

but when I access staging.mydomain.com via browser its not work.
[image: not work]

the weird here is, I can access directly via browser with URL myelasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

So I need help how to resolve this?
I need access myelasticbeanstalk via my subdomain only.

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your URL includes the region name `ap-southeast-1`, you need to use Route 53 Aliases.

> If the domain name includes the Region You can create an alias record.
> An alias record is specific to Route 53 and has two significant
> advantages over CNAME records:
>
> You can create alias records for the root domain name or for
> subdomains. For example, if your domain name is example.com, you can
> create a record that routes requests for example.com or for
> acme.example.com to your Elastic Beanstalk environment.
>
> Route 53 doesn't charge for requests that use an alias record to route
> traffic.

To create an Alias for Elastic beanstalk see the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-alias-procedure)

Comment: could you please more specific ? I am trying to create an alias but I dont see options for my elastic beanstalk.
This is the screenshot :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj35X-R_U5isqJO-mCLXASBLhuioKlz0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Select record type as `A – IPv4 address` and Route traffic to as `Alias to Elastic Beanstalk environment` then choose the Region in which your elastic beanstalk instance is in and choose the elastic beanstalk service which you want to route to

Comment: HI @Aman B ,
I already do same step like that, but it still does not work.

But now I think this different issue here, I can confirm it your suggestion working well.
But I try to route with CNAME without aliases, and it work also.
The problem here, I thought I can't access with SSL since my application redirect to https.
but I can access it well with HTTP 
Any other suggestions ? maybe this is caused by firewall or security group ?
Many thanks for your response

Comment: solved now, just add listener to my elastic beanstalk environment.
Thank you